# How to implement interstitial Admob ads in a Game using Xcode Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I made a game using Spritekit in Xcode using Objective-c, but I could not found a solution on how to implement Admob's interstitial ads.

I tried a lot of things and don't work.

So how can I open an interstitial ad in my game scene?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Admob code:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;
self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-****************/*********"];
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
        if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
           [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Ad wasn't ready");
        }
```

Xcode is giving me an warning:  Incompatible pointer types sending 'GameScene *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController * _Nonnull'

Comment: have you tried solution given in this link ? https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

Comment: Yes  I did, please have a look at the edit I made to the post.

Comment: I think this code doesn't work because is not a UIViewController

Comment: error you displayed has nothing to do with admob its error for RootViewController issue. See if you see any other error for admob

Comment: I don't see other errors. How can I fix the first one?